# PyCharm: how to avoid being asked to choose Configuration on launch?

Tags: python, pycharm

Every time I launch debug mode (F5) in PyCharm, I am being asked to choose the Configuration. Then I need to press "Enter". Can I avoid this, and use, for example, "main" configuration all the time?

Comment: It seems like you are executing [Choose configuration and debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/running-and-debugging.html). Make sure to execute [Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/running-and-debugging.html) instead.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio keymap - but yes, your comment led me to answer: Alt+F5 instead of just F5 is the solution to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Strange, I thought that Alt+Shift+F9 is default for VS keymap in pycharm.

Comment: remember to answer your own question. It's good practice and it's not arrogant if you found a solution on your own (and with @lifus hint) and want to share. People can benefit. :)

Comment: @mmassaro It involves custom shortcut. I don't think that anyone would benefit from that. If I were Danijel, I would remove it altogether or edit to make more general.

Comment: It's not a custom shortcut, it's the one you get if `Settings->Appearance & Behaviour->Keymap>Keymaps` is set to `Visual Studio`.

Comment: Yeah, I see now. It's `Main menu -> Run -> Resume Program`.